# Error using Accelstepper library in PlatformIO mbed

Tags: mbed, platformio

I have successfully instantiated my accelstepper objects:

```
//Create accelstepper object for the Z-Axis actuator
AccelStepper zaxis(AccelStepper::DRIVER, ZSTEP, ZDIR);

//Create accelstepper object for the theta axis actuator
AccelStepper taxis(AccelStepper::DRIVER, TSTEP, TDIR);

//Create accelstepper object for the magnet actuator
AccelStepper maxis(AccelStepper::DRIVER, MSTEP, MDIR);
```

Now I am trying to do some basic setup with these objects:

```
void stepper_setup(){

  //Set Max Speed in steps per second
  zaxis.setMaxSpeed(100);
  taxis.setMaxSpeed(100);
  maxis.setMaxSpeed(100);

  //Set Acceleration in steps per second squared
  zaxis.setAcceleration(500);
  taxis.setAcceleration(500);
  maxis.setAcceleration(500);

  //Home the Zaxis, Taxis, Maxis
  zaxis.moveTo(100000); taxis.moveTo(100000); maxis.moveTo(100000);
  zaxis.run(); taxis.run(); maxis.run();
```

However, the compiler throws me the following error:

```
.pio\build\nucleo_f410rb\lib799\libAccelStepper.a(AccelStepper.o): In function `AccelStepper::runSpeed()':
c:\Users\USER\Documents\PROJECTFOLDER\Codes\PROJECT TITLE/.pio\libdeps\nucleo_f410rb\AccelStepper/AccelStepper.cpp:63: undefined reference to `t'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** [.pio\build\nucleo_f410rb\firmware.elf] Error 1
```

and when look up the problematic line 63 in AccelStepper.cpp in question, i can only find this line:

```
 _currentPos -= 1;
```

[This is the picture of the problematic line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMk8A.png) and

[This is the picture of the error thrown in the compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWBli.png)

which doesn't make sense. Am I missing something? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there anything called `t` in your code? Could the indicated line be mangled by some macro? How is `currentPos` defined?

Comment: Hi Erlkoenig, there is no 't' in my main.cpp. `_currentPos` is defined in AccelStepper.h as `/// The current absolution position in steps.
    long           _currentPos;    // Steps`

Comment: @Erlkoenig, I seeing the only place where 't' is defined is under AccelStepper.cpp's `bool AccelStepper::runSpeed()
{
 extern Timer t;`
which is at line 43

Comment: That could be it. Is there a definition of `Timer t` somewhere? If not, that would cause the undefined reference error.

Comment: For the time being, removing the keyword "extern" has allowed the compiler to pass the code. I do not know if this is a good solution or not...

Comment: It's probably completely wrong, because now the code makes its own instance instead of using one that is correctly defined somewhere else. You are probably missing some other source file. However, this appears to be very bad coding style, naming a global variable `t`...

Comment: Is it [this one](https://os.mbed.com/users/Zeran/code/STM32F103C8T6_Stepper/file/f44fc4db4ab1/AccelStepper.cpp/)? Apparently, in your [main.cpp](https://os.mbed.com/users/Zeran/code/STM32F103C8T6_Stepper/file/f44fc4db4ab1/main.cpp), you need a "Timer t;". This is quite ugly...

Comment: Hi, I haven't had the opportunity to test it out yet. Thanks for pointing it out!